# Macro or inline function to iterate over OpenCV matrices

Tags: c++, opencv

Does OpenCV provide any macro or function to iterate over matrices without knowing their channel depth?

Eventually I implemented myself, but I wonder whether it was available already somewhere within the opencv source, or if there is a better way to achieve the same result?

```
#define CV_EVAL(src,i,j,c,dst)                                                                                                   \
    if(src.depth() == CV_8U) {                                                                                                       \
        dst = ((uchar*)(src.data))[ i*src.step1()+ j*src.channels() + c];    
    }                                                                                                                                                            \
  else if(src.depth() == CV_8S) {                                                                                              \
        dst = ((schar*)(src.data))[ i*src.step1()+ j*src.channels() + c];    
    }                                                                                                                                                            \
  else if(src.depth() == CV_16U) {                                                                                           \
        dst = ((ushort*)(src.data))[ i*src.step1()+ j*src.channels() + c];   
    }                                                                                                                                                            \
  else if(src.depth() == CV_16S) {                                                                                           \
        dst = ((short*)(src.data))[ i*src.step1()+ j*src.channels() + c];    
    }                                                                                                                                                            \
  else if(src.depth() == CV_32S) {                                                                                           \
        dst = ((int*)(src.data))[ i*src.step1()+ j*src.channels() + c];    
    }                                                                                                                                                            \
  else if(src.depth() == CV_32F) {                                                                                           \
        dst = ((float*)(src.data))[ i*src.step1()+ j*src.channels() + c];    
    }                                                                                                                                                            \
  else if(src.depth() == CV_64F) {                                                                                           \
        dst = ((double*)(src.data))[ i*src.step1()+ j*src.channels() + c];           \
    }                                                                                                                                                            \
  else {                                                                                                                                                 \
    CV_Assert(false);                                                                                                                        \
    }
```